# Zap Vaadin setup issues

Tags: authentication, owasp, zap

Being absolutely new to security testing, I am trying to run basic steps and then trying to run a spider and active scan. I have seen couple of videos from `owasp` & `youtube` and tried to make sense of the included ZAP documentation. However, I don't think ZAP is logged in while making the spider crawl or active scans.

Mine is a `Java` + `Vaadin & Spring` based application and the POST URL's don't change on making any kind of request. Just the request parameters change. POST URL's are always

> http://example.com/UIDL/?v-uiId=0

I have used

- Set Active Session under HTTP session, before running the spider/active scan
- have setup the context(though very few URL's appear under Sites),
- I have also tried to update structure parameter with words like "page", "UIDL" etc. which i could see in the URL's
- I have also tried to exclude logout URL, but since all the POST URL's are the same, the spider and active scan don't really do anything, in that case.
- On right clicking i got an option to select the request as Form based Authentication.

I have tried that as well, however, it populates the "Login Request POST data" with vaues like

> 12929ddf-5d7f-4264-b810-2fa8f38eca6f[["597","v","v",["pagelength",["i","28"]]],["597","v","v",["firstToBeRendered",["i","0"]]],["597","v","v",["lastToBeRendered",["i","26"]]],["597","v","v",["reqfirstrow",["i","15"]]],["597","v","v",["reqrows",["i","12"]]]]

and fills the username/password fields with exactly the same.

One last thing, do we really need to disable the `XSRF` to be able to use ZAP properly with `Java/Vaadin` applications?

I am simply trying to get it working and then continue learning from there. Would appreciate if anyone can please help me with the correct setup.

[image]

Comment: There are quite a few questions here :/ I can try to answer them here, but I'll end up pointing to the ZAP wiki which will then get my answer deleted :P I'd suggest answering this on the ZAP User Group: https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users which I think is a better forum for discussing these sort of setup issues.

Comment: Thanks @Psiinon , I have added it to google group. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/zaproxy-users/fi2PFMuZsPw/196trTIYEQAJ